# Unable to Start Acticity Component Info

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sqlite

In my project, I am trying to save data into a sqllite database and trying to read those data once its saved. I am able to write all the data in the database but while trying to retrieve the data then I am getting unable to start activity: Kotlin.kotlinNullPointerException error. I followed all the recommendation by android suggestion but still getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

**Language Used**

Kotlin

**Error**

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
```

**Code**

```
noteList = dbHandler!!.readNotes()
```

**Read Code**

```
 fun readNotes(): ArrayList<Notes>
    {
        var db=readableDatabase
        val list:ArrayList<Notes> = ArrayList()
        var selectAll = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME
        var cursor: Cursor = db.rawQuery(selectAll, null)
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                var note = Notes()
                note.id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))
                note.noteName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NOTE_NAME))
                list.add(note)
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        return list
    }
```

**Steps Checked**

```
1) Activity is presented in Android Manifest File
2) Data's are stored in the database
3) Text Views castings are done properly
```

Comment: Some object initialized as null. Check logs, there might be reference to the line where the error occurred.

Comment: I am getting error at this line notes.activity.NoteListActivity.onCreate(NoteListActivity.kt:39)

Comment: great, you can handle it: check for null using `if` operator.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dbHandler might be null. using !! asserts that the object is not null. Check if you have initialised the dbHandler or post the whole code

Comment: You are right. I have included this command and it worked for me. dbHandler=NotesDatabaseHandler(this). Thanks all for your suggestion.